# Unable to set the width of webkit-scrollbar-thumb

Tags: css, webkit

I am trying to style up a custom scrollbar that works in Chrome and Safari. I’ve tried the following CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .5);
    width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #818B99;
    border-radius: 9px;
    width: 9px;
}
```

However the `width` on the `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` is being ignored. I would like the thumb to be thinner than the track, as above.

It appears that I can fake the width by setting a border on the `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` of 3px with the same colour as the track, however this only works with an opaque background colour, and I need it to work with a transparent colour for the track as above.

Example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L6Uzu/1/

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You are correct that WebKit ignores the width declaration on the scrollbar-thumb. It also ignores it on the track.

The problem with using a `border` is that it draws the border within the thumb, so if you just make the colour `transparent`, it will not work.

The solution is to change where the background is attached. By default the background extends under the border, as mentioned. You can use the `background-clip` property to change this, so that it only extends to the edge of the padding box instead. Then you just need to make a 3px transparent border, then Bob’s your uncle:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #818B99;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 9px;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/L6Uzu/3/

This works correctly in Chrome, but Safari doesn’t have as advanced a border-radius implementation, so the rounded corners are not visible.

Comment: Thanks David! I wasn't aware of background-clip.