# Change size of scrollbar thumb with CSS

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I want to get a scrollbar with a thumb larger than the track.
I can change the color, the opacity, everything, but I don't know how to change the size of the thumbs and the track separately.

```css
.custom_scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 1px;
 
}
.custom_scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
}
.custom_scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
 background-color: rgb(142, 142, 142);
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-width:5;
}
.custom_scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover {
 background: rgba(0, 245, 255, 0.65);
}

#page {
    width: 75%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 30;
    margin: 5%;
    padding: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page" class=".custom_scrollbar">
  <h1>cool</h1>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  <p>text text text text text text text text FIN :D </p>
</div>
```

This is what I want it to look like:

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to do it is assigning border on either side of the track

> ```
>   border-left: 3px solid white;
>   border-right: 3px solid white;
> ```

CSS

```
.cute_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #f8bbd0  ;

}

.cute_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #f06292 ;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f8bbd0  ;

    // Add Border on Track
    border-left: 3px solid white;
    border-right: 3px solid white;

}

.cute_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 px #ad1457 ;
    background-color: #e91e63   ;

}
```

**Result**

https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/eGQOwJ

[image]

Answer (score 38):

This is a really old post, but I have a working solution that does 'EXACTLY' what was asked for. Also, this will come in handy for anybody else needing this solution.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfj4L6wL/)

```
/* SCROLLBAR */
/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;   /* THIS IS IMPORTANT */
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgb(25,25,25);
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

It is very important to set background-clip: content-box for this to work. You will be left with a track that is thinner than the scroll-bar-thumb. Cheers!!

Comment: Amazing, but is there any way to reduce the height of the scrollbar track too?

Comment: This is not doing what the OP wanted as far as I can see in Chrome. The thumb is not larger than the track.

Comment: Both the thumb and the track are the same size, doesn't do what OP has asked

Answer (score 6):

To make the thumb smaller than the track/scrollbar, simply add a border to the thumb having the same color as the track.

http://jsfiddle.net/Swiftaxe/75pmwmfw/

```css
.wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    background: white;
    max-height: 90px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
}

.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
  background: #CCEEF4;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  width: 24px;
  background: #49AEC0;
  border: 5px solid #CCEEF4;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Scrolling is a Virtue</h1>
    <p>Well, it's not the first time. About it! There; keep thy finger on it. This is a cogent vice thou hast here, carpenter; let me feel its grip once. So, so; it does pinch some. Oh, sir, it will break bones—beware, beware! No fear; I like a good grip; I like to feel something in this slippery world that can hold, man.</p>
</div>
```

If the track needs to be transparent one can use background-clip.

[Unable to set the width of webkit-scrollbar-thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819116/unable-to-set-the-width-of-webkit-scrollbar-thumb)

Comment: This was very helpfull and educative

Comment: The OP wants the thumb larger than the track, not smaller.

Answer (score 4):

You can setup your size using width in `::-webkit-scrollbar`.

I don't think it is possible to set separately the thumb and track size.

http://jsfiddle.net/rvcfmun7/

```
.test {
    overflow: auto;
    background gray ;
    max-height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
}

.test::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 20px;
}

.test::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background: rgb(41,41,41);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    width: 15px;
    background: rgb(111,111,111);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer its really IMPOSSIBLE ;) green check

Answer (score 0):

You can use a background image to make it look like the scrollbar is smaller than the thumb.

```css
.custom_scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}
.custom_scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  /* This image is smaller than the width of the scrollbar-thumb */
  background: url('scroll-bg.gif') center 0 repeat-y;
}
.custom_scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
  width: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background: url(../../images/scroll-bg.jpg) repeat-y 50%;}
```

Background is 1px point.

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
    height: 100%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked for: Having the thumb be larger than the track.

Answer (score 0):

Just set border to scroll bar and make both background color and scrollbar border color same, like if your background color is white than set same for scrollbar's border-color.

```
p {
  width: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* set border-color of scrollbar and background color of that section same */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #888;
}
```

html:

```
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**To customize Scrollbar**
    .custom_scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
     background: transparent;
     width: 8px;
     height: 0px;
}
 .custom_scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
     height: 56px;
     border-radius: 8px;
     border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
     background-clip: content-box;
     background-color: #000000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/techieRaj/vonu9w3x/4/

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked for: Having the thumb be larger than the track.