# CSS Scroll thumb fixed circle size

Tags: css, scrollbar

I want to style a scroll bar thumb as a fixed circle, there is something I'm missing because I cant fix height size. Now what is happening is that depending on how long the scroll bar is, how long the thumb is too, and I'd like to get a fixed circle no matters how long the scroll bar is.
Here is what I have:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.list1 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
}

.list1::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
}

.list1::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.list1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 border-radius: 100px;
 background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list1">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="list1">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, depending on how many items i have is the hight that the scroll bar thumb will take. Below the way I want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set a height value in the `.list1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`:

```
.list1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  height:50px;
}
```

---

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.list1 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
}
.list1::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
}
.list1::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.list1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid blue;height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list1">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="list1">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having a problem: if i change height size from scroll, the i like disappear... any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca what do you mean by "the i like disappear"? And change the height of which element?

Comment: Sorry, what i mean is that if i change list's heigh, for example to 200px, thumb changes its height too. Try changing list's heigh to 200px, I hope this [fiddle](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/QdNQej) let you understand what I mean. Thanks!!

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493446/change-size-of-scrollbar-thumb-with-css).