# How to create custom scollbar using vanilla css/vanilla js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, mcustomscrollbar

I want to create a dictionary-like feature where I want to design a custom scroll bar.
I can customize it using CSS but it is up to some extent. I can't achieve what I want.
Any help is appreciated.

This is what I want

[image]

This is what I can able to customize (ignore color)

[image]

```css
.scrolling-area::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px #fff;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid $primary;
    border-right: 4px solid $primary;
  }
  .scrolling-area::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 px #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
```

**Note:**
I saw one [jquery plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html)  offer this type of scrollbar
But I want to do it using vanilla js or vuejs specific solution also appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Scroll thumb fixed circle size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598048/css-scroll-thumb-fixed-circle-size)

Comment: Nope, image shows expected result but given code prints something different.