# Scrollbar Thumb Height

Tags: css

Lately, I was in a situation, where I had to style the scrollbar thumb. Every styling was going good, except the height one. Setting the `height` and `max-height` didn't have at any effect on the scroll bar at all. I tried setting a fixed height in `px` for the DOM element, still no changes at all...

Then, I came through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755144/scrollbar-thumb-height-in-css), which says that setting scrollbar thumb height is not possible because its height of the scrollbar is always relative to the content of the DOM element.

But here is a [live example](https://imgur.com/PQz0jxT) of Google using the `max-height` property. Can anyone tell, what's going on here?

Meanwhile, my code is:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0); 
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgb(var(--bg-80)); 
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: rgb(var(--bg-100)); 
}
```