# Scrollbar color in Opera

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webkit, opera

I am trying to change the background color of a vertical scrollbar on a div, so it should not be white in the dark mode in my react app.

None of the webkit-based styling solutions I could find worked in Opera. Neither could I find a way with `react-custom-scrollbars-2` package. I would be fine with any solution, be it CSS or JavaScript-based.

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/scrollbar-color-sfndxh?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvzspcw00063j6ictegmtn2%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvzspcw00023j6ig448hmxq%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvzspcw00033j6ipnw1xqz3%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvzspcw00053j6i6hh0axl3%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsvzspcw00023j6ig448hmxq%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvzspcw00023j6ig448hmxq%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clsvzspcw00053j6i6hh0axl3%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvzspcw00043j6i3yw5rto4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvzspcw00053j6i6hh0axl3%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsvzspcw00043j6i3yw5rto4%2522%257D%252C%2522clsvzspcw00033j6ipnw1xqz3%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvzspcw00033j6ipnw1xqz3%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styling scrollbars always seems a not-so-simple task. Personally, I always prefer `-webkit-scrollbar` and `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` for implementing this.
Here is the CSS for the same:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
  /* background-color: #custom_bg_color; */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #6d6d6d;
  /* border-radius: 10px; */
  /* height: 20px; */
}
```

Comment: It does work! But if I remove the first rule, the second one does not work. Why can't I change the background color without changing the width?

Comment: Also, in contrast to the standard, it does not show the arrows at the extremities of the scrollbar and the thumb occupies the whole width of the scrollbar. Can I make the arrows show and make the thumb narrow, while keeping the scrollbar wide?

Comment: Solution to the narrow thumb problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16829330/2725810

Comment: Solution to the arrow problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66050759/2725810

Comment: As far as I know, to make thumb work, you must have a defined (custom) width for the scrollbar.

Comment: The links you provided work fine. Just a suggestion, it is always less complicated to keep minimum properties for scrollbar styling as after a while it becomes hard to debug/modify the style as they are highly co-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `webkit` styling itself.

```
:root {
  --bg-color: #282c34; // here set a variable to represent the bg color
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color); // use the pre-defined color variable
  color: white;
}

//override the scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: var(--bg-color); //here set scrollbar bg-color
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; // here you can set scrollbar thumb color
}
```

Comment: The question is about Opera, which does not support `-webkit-scrollbar`. I tried to put this into the sandbox and it did not make a difference.